# Open IManDocument in browser

Tags: c#, autonomy, imanage, worksite-sdk

I am using the WorkSite COM API to open an `IMANEXT2Lib.IManFileOpenDlg` which is working perfectly. Clicking on the document, I can retrieve the metadata, such as the document name, version, number etc.

Is there a method or technique available to read the document from WorkSite and prompt a download/open through a browser?

The `IManage.IManDocument` has the method `GetCopy()` available which will download a local copy to a specified directory, but this isn't really what I'm after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the clients have Worksite 8.5 or greater, you can use the IWL protocol in a hyperlink to force the client to use the IWL handler to download and launch the file themselves instead of streaming it from the browser. This has the added benefit of respecting the document's permissions and checking the document out to the user so they can make amends to the file if required.

An IWL formatted anchor tag in a web browser would look like the following:

```
<a href="iwl:dms=DMSSERVERNAME&lib=DATABASENAME&num=DOCNUM&ver=VERSION&latest=1">Document x</a>
```

Note that this will only work if the clients have Worksite 8.5 or newer installed.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will give it a go soon and get back to you.

Comment: Is there a way to force getting a read-only copy, rather than checking the document out?

Comment: Yes, you can specify the command openROCmd   - for example: iwl:dms=DMSSERVERNAME&lib=DATABASENAME&num=DOCNUM&ver=VERSION&latest=1&command=openROCmd.

Comment: I received error message when I tried  command=o‌​penROCmd, but if I change it all lower case &command=o‌​penrocmd, then it works fine.  Thank you.